# how to fill NA with 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to fill NA value to my dataset. I am not sure if it is possible to do as following or not:

I have 3 columns, I want to fill NA of distance out

```
         duration    distance       mode
           15            7            car
            20           6             walk
           13            NA             car
            20           8             car
            18           NA            walk
           30           10            walk
```

for each mode I want to find closest duration and put in NA for distance

for mode car , the closest duration to 13 is 15 so first NA is 7, for second NA (which is walk mode), the closest duration to 18 is 20 so NA is 6.

Comment: `na_if` should help you with NA values. See: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html 

I don't understand the explanation of how you want the NA to be introduced to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: the third column is mode of travel , first column is duration of travel. NA is in distance column. I want to fill distance with respect of duration and mode of travel. for each mode I want to find closest duration and put distance of that trip in my NA row

Comment: Aha, so you wan to put a value in place of the NA? I thought you wanted to be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way in base R could be to separate `NA` and non-NA groups. For every value in `NA_group`  we find the closest `duration` in `non_NA_group` in same `mode` and return the corresponding `distance`.

```
NA_group <- subset(df, is.na(distance))
non_NA_group <- subset(df, !is.na(distance))

df$distance[is.na(df$distance)] <- mapply(function(x, y) {
    temp <- subset(non_NA_group, mode == y)
    temp$distance[which.min(abs(x - temp$duration))]
} ,NA_group$duration, NA_group$mode)

df
#  duration distance mode
#1       15        7  car
#2       20        6 walk
#3       13        7  car
#4       20        8  car
#5       18        6 walk
#6       30       10 walk
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt[is.na(distance),
   distance := {dt[!is.na(distance)
                   ][.SD,
                     on = .(mode),
                     distance[which.min(abs(duration - i.duration))],
                     by = .EACHI]$V1
     }
   ]

dt

#   duration distance mode
#1:       15        7  car
#2:       20        6 walk
#3:       13        7  car
#4:       20        8  car
#5:       18        6 walk
#6:       30       10 walk
#7:       35       10 walk
```

It:

1. Subsets the dataframe to only allow `na` values
2. Self-joins with the only `non_NA` values based on the `mode` of transportation.
3. Determines which is the minimum distance.

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
DT <-          fread('duration    distance       mode
15            7            car
20           6             walk
13            NA             car
20           8             car
18           NA            walk
30           10            walk
35            NA            walk')
```

Comment: it is filling everything by 3.76

Comment: Are there multiple NAs per group? Is there also some kind of ID associated with a mode group?

Comment: @hghg see edit - I tested it with a second ```NA``` value and it seems to be good to go.